# python pandas - get unique count, description text sample (similar to mysql group_concat)

Tags: python, pandas

say i have sample data like this

[image]

and i want to generate summary dataframe with sample text of the desc1 and desc2 for a large data set.. (about 20,000 rows)

I will have more columns like desc3, desc4, etc... and i may want to include additional desc_n samples in the result.

[image]

The purpose is to get an idea of what the unique names are (group by).. then see a sample text for the other fields concatenated and count of unique desc1

Comment: Reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) on good pandas questions might be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
# customized aggregation function
join_unique = lambda x: ','.join(set(x))

# aggregate columns desc1 and desc2 respectively
df1 = df.groupby('name').agg({'desc1': [join_unique, 'nunique'], 'desc2': join_unique})

# rename columns
df1.columns = ['_'.join(x) if x[1] == 'nunique' else x[0] + "_samp" for x in df1.columns]

df1   # call reset_index() if necessary
```

[image]

Comment: excellent!!!... i need to practice on this more to get a good understanding to use with my real data. Thank you.